# Programming of BlueGiga Bluetooth module

Tags: ios, configuration, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hardware

I have a BlueGiga bluetooth module (BLE121LR-A-M256K), supporting BLE. I need to configure the module by transferring a bgscript to the module. Can I transfer this bgscript through a bluetooth connection between module and computer, or how is this done?

In short my project is: Measure a Strain Gauge resistance, get the information to the Bluetooth module, and connect bluetooth module with IPad, and then you can see the resistance in the Strain Gauge wireless on IPad.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To use BGScript, you have to use the SiLabs toolchain flow. At a high level, it's something like this:

1) Install [Silicon Labs Simplicity Studio](https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/simplicity-studio) and setup your target device

2) Create a BGScript project file, hardware config file and GATT XML database to go with your BCScript source code

3) Compile project using BGTool to generate binary image

4) Download image to target using BGTool over a programming cable. Optionally, you can use the OTA (over-the-air) update mechanism, but setup is non-trivial.

You can't transfer BSCript source code directly to a device, you need to use the flow above.

You can find a lot of resources [here](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth). Please note that SiLabs has deprecated the BGScript flow. It still works, but the last Bluetooth SDK that supports it is ver 2.3.3. SiLabs is encouraging new designs to use their C/GCC flow.

Answer (score 0):

BLE121-?? products are Bluegiga legacy products and are not programmed with Simplicity Studio. You find SDK for BLE121 from here
https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/bluegiga-bluetooth-smart-software-stack and it includes PC tools needed to upload the software.

Haven't used this product lately but at least there is serial line update of the firmware and. If you develop a script application and want to use the serial line update be sure to add some interrupt handler for entering the DFU mode.